# Puppet Module Resources

Tags: puppet

Instead of continually writing my own modules to convert systems into puppet management, I would prefer to leverage the community as much as possible.  So far I have come across two sites that compile modules for distribution, [Puppet Wiki](http://www.reductivelabs.com/trac/puppet/tags/puppet%2Crecipe) and [Puppet Managed](http://puppetmanaged.org).  What else is out there, and/or what have you found useful?

Comment: I think you mean Puppet Forge, I'm not sure where you got Puppet Managed from.  http://forge.puppetlabs.com/

Comment: @JoshuaHoblitt Because in 2009 when I asked this question PuppetForge didn't exist and Puppet Managed was still a big resource. It looks like there are fewer modules for distribution there now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Also check that page http://reductivelabs.com/trac/puppet/wiki/PuppetModules .

Comment: ... as there is a list of Module Collections on there, and it should form the canonical reference to the available collections.

Answer (score 5):

Here's another (not sure if those are all the same content, but they look like it)

- http://live.lab42.it/puppetinfrastructure/
- http://www.example42.com/

There's a goal by some to make modules "reusable" and general purpose enough that they can easily be used across many sites.  My experience, however, has been that very few modules can simply be dropped in due to all sorts of assumptions.  There's lots of good examples out there, though.

Answer (score 1):

Searching [GitHub](http://github.org/) repository names for 'puppet' will find you quite a few - the standard naming for a puppet module seems to be 'puppet-{module-name}', eg puppet-apache.

[This link](http://github.com/search?langOverride=&language=&q=puppet&repo=&start_value=1) should take you to the results.